# Self Join in Spring Boot Data JPA - Showing only the first child node (0th element) not all children nodes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The use case which I wanted to use in the application is that I have a list and the list will have many children and the children will have children and so on. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

And in order to achieve this hierarchy I have created the Java Class following;

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String type;
    
    @Column(name = "READONLY")
    private Boolean readOnly;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT")
    private Item parent;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> children = new HashSet<Item>();

}
```

The Insertion works fine. But when I retreive data I am not getting all the childeren nodes under a parent in the `Set<Item> children` but getting only the first childeren ie; 0th element in the Set. I  have no idea on the issue here, what am I doing wrong. I am getting output as given below;

```
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "PARENT 1",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "6",
          "type": "CHILDREN 1",
          "parent": 1,
          "readOnly": false,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": " PARENT 2",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": " PARENT 3",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "type": " PARENT 4",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "type": " PARENT 5",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "type": "CHILDREN 1",
      "parent": 1,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "type": "CHILDREN 1",
      "parent": 1,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**WHERE I SUPPOSED TO GET OUTPUT AS THIS;**

```
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "PARENT 1",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "6",
          "type": "CHILDREN 1",
          "parent": 1,
          "readOnly": false,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "type": "CHILDREN 1",
          "parent": 1,
          "readOnly": false,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": " PARENT 2",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": " PARENT 3",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "type": " PARENT 4",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "type": " PARENT 5",
      "parent": null,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "type": "CHILDREN 1",
      "parent": 1,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "type": "CHILDREN 1",
      "parent": 1,
      "readOnly": false,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Where in the first item I should be getting 2 children, but instead getting a single child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem could be related with the `equals` implementation of the `Item` class: you are using `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` to instruct Lombok to only include the fields or methods you wish in the `equals`implementation but you are not annotating any field or method with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include`. Please, see the [relevant docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode).

By this reason Lombok probably is generating an `equals` implementation that originates that every `Item` is considered to be equal to another and thus the `children` `Set` only contains information about the first `Item`added.

Please, annotate the fields you consider appropriate with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include`, I think it will do the trick. For instance:

```java
//...
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Long id;
```

Comment: Where were you? Thank you. You saved me.

Comment: You are welcome @SebinThomas! I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful